# is it possible to display only a particular echo response from server using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to figure out how to just display a particular response from php using ajax for example. I have a php which gives the following response -

```
echo 'Success'; //Display only this

//Some other process

echo 'Something else for other process';
```

JS

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: {action: 'test'},
    dataType:'JSON', 
    success: function(response){
        $( '#name_status' ).html(response);   
    }
});
```

Comment: Just change `dataType:'JSON'` to `dataType:'HTML'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `if else`.

And while sending AJAX request, send conditional parameters.

For example, `flag`: set it to either `yes` or `no`.

Get these parameters `$_POST` ed in PHP back end.

Depending upon the value of AJAX sent parameter, print the response.

`JS:`

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "some.php",
data: {action: 'test', 'flag' : 'yes'},
dataType:'JSON', 
success: function(response){
   $( '#name_status' ).html(response);   
}
});
```

Set `flag` to `yes` or `no` // This is just sample.

In PHP,

```
if (isset($_POST['flag'] && $_POST['flag'] == 'yes') {
  echo 'Success'; //Display only this
}
else {
  echo 'Something else for other process';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have send `json_encode` to receive a JSON response and will have to accordingly change the PHP too. Below is the updated code that you can try:

PHP:

```
if($_POST['action'] == 'test') {
    $returnArray = array('message' => 'Success'); 
} else {
   $returnArray = array('message' => 'Something else for other process');
}
echo json_encode($returnArray);
```

JS

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: {
    action: 'test'
  },
  dataType: 'JSON',
  success: function(response) {
    var responseObj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
    $('#name_status').html(responseObj.message);
  }
});
```

Comment: I am unable to print $('#name_status').html(response.message);   i am able to print if i remove message from it.

Comment: Did you check console? Also add `console.log(response)` in success function and check what you are receiving in your console.

Comment: console.log(response) result -- {"message":"Success"}     &                 console.log(response.message) result -- "undefined"

Comment: I have updated the code by adding `var responseObj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);`. We need to parse JSON as the response is JSON.

Comment: Well thank you that did solve the problem but my actual issue is still unsolved i have lots of other stuff going on in the code which echo's different values for other process. Therefore there is a uncaught syntax error in json.

Comment: Well, since we can't see and don't know your additional other stuff as well as syntax errors, we can't really help much. If this has solved your issue and helped you move to next step, you can vote and mark this as done.